# MySQL empty set literal

Tags: mysql, set, coalesce

I have a column of type `set` (of elements). I would like to select either the set itself if it `IS NOT NULL`, or an empty set if it `IS NULL`.

What I'm trying to figure out is the right syntax for

```
SELECT COALESCE(the_set, '{}')
```

in MySQL.

Specifically, I'm looking for an empty set MySQL literal.

Google didn't help me so far :(

Comment: I don't get the problem. Use `null` or `''`

Comment: Though SETs are stored as bitmasks, they are represented by strings. So an empty SET is just an empty string. If you don't like it, consider to use JSON, or normalize your table.